# APN settings change

Tags: android

How one could the programmatically change the APN settings , so they are invalidated ?

Answer (score 8):

Check the following  links

[Managing APN Settings on Google Android](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zhengpei/archive/2009/10/13/managing-apn-data-in-google-android.aspx)

[APN data access toggle for Android](http://code.google.com/p/apndroid/)

Hope this will help you..