# change APN Settings in Android for all OS versions 2.2 onwards

Tags: android, apn

How to programmatically change APN Settings in Android for all OS versions 2.2 onwards?
Is it possible to change them on OS versions 4.0 onwards?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773639/apn-settings-change Also I'd be mad if your app started messing with my APN settings, especially if you're assuming I'm on a specific carrier. APN Settings for Rogers Wireless will not work on AT&T without incurring fees, or not working at all.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have a code that works for pre-2.2 Android? Have you tried running it on 2.2+ devices/emulators? What were the results?