# InsertAPN() Method Does Not Write APN Settings - Android 2.3.6

Tags: java, android, android-contentresolver, android-cursor, access-point-name

I have an android application which is supposed to write new APN settings to a device however every time I run the application the new APN settings do not appear to be written to the device (the APN settings are totally blank after execution) I belive this may have something to do with a problem with InsertAPN() [shown below] however I'm unable to determine the root cause of the issue.

P.S.

Any debugging tips/questions are greatly appreciated.

SOURCE SNIPPET:

```
/*
 * Insert a new APN entry into the system APN table Require an apn name, and
 * the apn address. More can be added. Return an id (_id) that is
 * automatically generated for the new apn entry.
 */
public int InsertAPN() throws SecurityException {

    int id = -1;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        ContentValues values2 = new ContentValues();
        // values2 = values1;
        values2 = getValues();
        ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor c = null;
        try {
            Uri newRow = resolver.insert(APN_TABLE_URI, values2);
            // System.out.println("values in insertAPN" + values1);
            if (newRow != null) {
                c = resolver.query(newRow, null, null, null, null);
                Log.d(TAG, "Newly added APN:");
                // TF Settings have been inserted
                // Obtain the apn id
                int idindex = c.getColumnIndex("_id");
                c.moveToFirst();
                id = c.getShort(idindex);

                Log.d(TAG, "New ID: " + id
                        + ": Inserting new APN succeeded!");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        if (c != null)
            c.close();
    }
    return id;

}
```

FULL SOURCE:

```
public class ConfigFinalActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "ConfigActivity";
    TelephonyManager tm;
    AlertDialog mErrorAlert = null;
    private Notification mNotification = null;
    private Button mXButton = null;
    private Button mAssistUpdateButton = null;
    private Button mAssistInstrButton = null;
    private Button mReadAgainButton = null;
    private int mInstructionNumber = 0;
    public static ArrayList<String> NameArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> ValueArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> nameArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> ApnArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmscArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmsportArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> mmsproxyArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> portArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<String> proxyArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static int count;
    public static int TotalSteps = 8;
    int i, g = 0, result = 0;

    public static ContentValues Values = new ContentValues();
    XmlParserHandlerFinal handler;

    public static final Uri APN_TABLE_URI = Uri
            .parse("content://telephony/carriers");
    public static final String Base_URL = "https://wapgate.example.com/REST/phoneSettings";
    public static InputStream stream = null;
    UpdateActivity update;
    public static String status, queryResult = "";

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        int version = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        update = new UpdateActivity();
        handler = new XmlParserHandlerFinal();
        handler.setContext(this.getBaseContext());
        getArrayLists();
        /*
         * boolean deleted = deleteFile("settings.xml");if(deleted){
         * Log.v("settings.xml","deleted"); }else
         * Log.v("settings.xml","failed to delete the file");
         */
        if (ApnArr.isEmpty() || mmscArr.isEmpty()) {

            tryagain();
        } else if (version < VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {

            // Update APN table
            try {
                result = updateTable();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }// Settings updated with this atomic call
            catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (result != -1) {
                status = "success";

            } else {
                status = "failure";
            }

            if (status.equals("success")) {
                completeUpdate();
            } else if (status.equals("failure")) {
                 tryagain();
                // showAlert(getString(R.string.unchanged_dialog));
            }

        } else {// ICS and later versions

            // Reduce number of steps to 6
            TotalSteps = 6;
            setContentView(R.layout.assist_instructions);
            String assistUpdate = getString(R.string.instructions_1);
            CharSequence styledText = Html.fromHtml(assistUpdate);
            TextView assistText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apn_app_text_cta2);
            assistText.setText(styledText);
            mAssistUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_update_btn);
            mAssistUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        }
    }

    private void getArrayLists() {
        nameArr = update.getnameArr();
        ApnArr = update.getApnArr();
        mmscArr = update.getMMSCArr();
        mmsproxyArr = update.getMmscProxyArr();
        mmsportArr = update.getMmsPortArr();
        proxyArr = update.getProxyArr();
        portArr = update.getPortArr();
        count = update.getCount();  
        queryResult = update.getResult();
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == mAssistUpdateButton) {

            // Update button for ICS and up is selected
            // Get the TextView in the Assist Update UI

            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.apn_app_text_cta2);
            String text = "";
            CharSequence styledText = text;
            switch (mInstructionNumber) {

            case 0:
                // Retrieve the instruction string resource corresponding the
                // 2nd set of instructions
                text = String.format(getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr),
                        TotalSteps);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
                // Update the TextView with the correct set of instructions
                tv.setText(styledText);
                // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
                // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
                // button is pressed
                mInstructionNumber++;
                break;
            case 1:
                text = getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr2);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(text);
                tv.setText(styledText);
                // Increment instruction number so the correct instructions
                // string resource can be retrieve the next time the update
                // button is pressed
                mInstructionNumber++;
                break;
            case 2:
                // Final set of instructions-Change to the corresponding layout

                setContentView(R.layout.assist_instructions);
                String assistUpdateInstr = String.format(
                        getString(R.string.apn_app_text_instr3), TotalSteps);
                styledText = Html.fromHtml(assistUpdateInstr);
                TextView assistInstrText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.updated_text);
                assistInstrText.setText(styledText);
                mAssistInstrButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assist_instr_btn);

                mAssistInstrButton.setOnClickListener(this);

            }
        } else if (v == mAssistInstrButton) {
            // "LET'S DO THIS" Button in final instructions screen for ICS and
            // up is selected
            Values = getValues();
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS));
            try {
                showNotification();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finish();
        } else if (v == mAssistInstrButton) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS));
            try {
                showNotification();
            } catch (SAXException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                showNotification();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finish();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Insert a new APN entry into the system APN table Require an apn name, and
     * the apn address. More can be added. Return an id (_id) that is
     * automatically generated for the new apn entry.
     */
    public int InsertAPN() throws SecurityException {

        int id = -1;
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            ContentValues values2 = new ContentValues();
            // values2 = values1;
            values2 = getValues();
            ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
            Cursor c = null;
            try {
                Uri newRow = resolver.insert(APN_TABLE_URI, values2);
                // System.out.println("values in insertAPN" + values1);
                if (newRow != null) {
                    c = resolver.query(newRow, null, null, null, null);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Newly added APN:");
                    // TF Settings have been inserted
                    // Obtain the apn id
                    int idindex = c.getColumnIndex("_id");
                    c.moveToFirst();
                    id = c.getShort(idindex);

                    Log.d(TAG, "New ID: " + id
                            + ": Inserting new APN succeeded!");
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
            if (c != null)
                c.close();
        }
        return id;

    }

    public ContentValues getValues() {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put("name", nameArr.get(i));
        values.put("apn", ApnArr.get(i));
        values.put("mmsc", mmscArr.get(i));
        //values.put("mmsproxy", mmsproxyArr.get(i));
        //values.put("mmsport", mmsportArr.get(i));
        // values.put("proxy", proxyArr.get(i));
         values.put("port", portArr.get(i));
        values.put("mcc", (getString(R.string.mcc)));
        if ((tm.getSimOperator()).equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo))) {
            values.put("numeric", getString(R.string.numeric_tmo));
            values.put("mnc", (getString(R.string.mnc_tmo)));
        } else if ((tm.getSimOperator())
                .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att))) {
            values.put("numeric", getString(R.string.numeric_att));
            values.put("mnc", (getString(R.string.mnc_att)));
        }
        return values;
    }
    /*
     * Delete APN data where the indicated field has the values Entire table is
     * deleted if both field and value are null
     */
    private void DeleteAPNs(String field, String[] values)
            throws SecurityException {
        int c = 0;
        c = getContentResolver().delete(APN_TABLE_URI, null, null);
        if (c != 0) {
            String s = "APNs Deleted:\n";
            Log.d(TAG, s);

        }

    }

    /*
     * Return all column names stored in the string array
     */
    private String getAllColumnNames(String[] columnNames) {
        String s = "Column Names:\n";
        for (String t : columnNames) {
            s += t + ":\t";
        }
        return s + "\n";
    }

    /*
     * Copy all data associated with the 1st record Cursor c. Return a
     * ContentValues that contains all record data.
     */
    private ContentValues copyRecordFields(Cursor c) {
        if (c == null)
            return null;
        int row_cnt = c.getCount();
        Log.d(TAG, "Total # of records: " + row_cnt);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();//
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            String[] columnNames = c.getColumnNames();
            Log.d(TAG, getAllColumnNames(columnNames));
            String row = "";
            for (String columnIndex : columnNames) {
                int i = c.getColumnIndex(columnIndex);
                row += c.getString(i) + ":\t";
                // if (i>0)//Avoid copying the id field
                // id to be auto-generated upon record insertion
                values.put(columnIndex, c.getString(i));
            }
            row += "\n";
            Log.d(TAG, row);
            Log.d(TAG, "End Of Records");
        }
        return values;
    }

    // showAlert displays the text contained in message as an alert
    public void showAlert(String message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(message).setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                ConfigFinalActivity.this.finish();
            }
        });
        mErrorAlert = builder.create();
        mErrorAlert.show();
    }

    // showErrorAlert displays an alert with layout and a title
    private void showErrorAlert(int layoutRes, String title) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = ConfigFinalActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();

        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        builder.setTitle(title)
        .setView(inflater.inflate(layoutRes, null))
        .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.assisted_button),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                startActivity(new Intent(
                        Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS));
                try {
                    showNotification();
                } catch (SAXException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        mErrorAlert = builder.create();
        mErrorAlert.show();
    }

    // showNotification starts the process of sending notifications to the bar
    // to assist the user in updating the data settings on ICS and later
    // versions of Android
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")    
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    public void showNotification() throws SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {

        String field = getString(R.string.config_name_label);

        String value = Values.get("name").toString();
        int mId = 1;
        String title = "1 of " + UpdateActivity.TotalSteps + " (Update "
                + field + ":)";
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notifications_icon)
                .setContentTitle(title).setContentText(value);
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this,
                NotificationActivityForMultiProf.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra(field, value);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                getApplicationContext(), 0, resultIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
        mNotification = mBuilder.getNotification();
        mNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        mNotificationManager.notify(mId, mNotification);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (mNotification != null) {
            outState.putString("NOTIFICATIONB", mNotification.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        if (mErrorAlert != null)
            mErrorAlert.dismiss();
    }

    private int updateTable() throws IOException, SAXException,
    ParserConfigurationException {
        int insertResult = -1;
        // returned value if table is not properly updated

        try {

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            // Query the carrier table for the current data settings
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(APN_TABLE_URI, null,
                    "current=?", new String[] { "1" }, null);
            values = copyRecordFields(c);
            // Copy the settings into values

            // Replace T-Mo/ATT Data settings if there is no SIM or
            // NET10/T-Mo/ATT SIM is
            // present
            if (tm.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT
                    || (tm.getSimOperator())
                    .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo))) {

                // delete all APNs before adding new APNs
                DeleteAPNs("numeric=?",
                        new String[] { getString(R.string.numeric_tmo) });
                // Insert Data Settings into Carrier table

                insertResult = InsertAPN();

            } else if (tm.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT
                    || (tm.getSimOperator())
                    .equals(getString(R.string.numeric_att))) {
                // Delete all APNs before adding new APNs
                DeleteAPNs("numeric=?",
                        new String[] { getString(R.string.numeric_att) });
                // Insert Data Settings into Carrier table

                insertResult = InsertAPN();

            } else
                // non NET10/ non T-Mo SIM/non ATT SIM
                showAlert(getString(R.string.insert_sm_dialog));
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            showErrorAlert(R.layout.assisted_setting,
                    getString(R.string.assited_title));
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return insertResult;
    }

    private void completeUpdate() {
        // Displaying final layout after pre-ICS automatic settings update
        setContentView(R.layout.completion);
        TextView mCompleted = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.done_text);
        String mDoneText = String.format(getString(R.string.done_text));
        CharSequence styledText = Html.fromHtml(mDoneText);

        mCompleted.setText(styledText);
        mXButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.x_button);
        mXButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

     public void tryagain() {
     // Displaying final layout after failure of pre-ICS automatic settings
     // update
     setContentView(R.layout.tryagain);
     String tryAgainText = "";
     CharSequence styledTryAgainText;

     tryAgainText = String.format(getString(R.string.tryagain_text1),
     TotalSteps);
     styledTryAgainText = Html.fromHtml(tryAgainText);
     TextView tryAgain1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tryagain_text1);
     tryAgain1.setText(styledTryAgainText);

     tryAgainText = String.format(getString(R.string.tryagain_text2),
     TotalSteps);
     styledTryAgainText = Html.fromHtml(tryAgainText);
     TextView tryAgain2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tryagain_text2);
     tryAgain2.setText(styledTryAgainText);

     tryAgainText = String.format(getString(R.string.tryagain_text3),
     TotalSteps);
     styledTryAgainText = Html.fromHtml(tryAgainText);
     TextView tryAgain3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tryagain_text3);
     tryAgain3.setText(styledTryAgainText);

     }

    // This function return a cursor to the table holding the
    // the APN configurations (Carrier table)
    public Cursor getConfigTableCursor() {
        return getContentResolver()
                .query(APN_TABLE_URI, null, null, null, null);
    }

}
```

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773639/apn-settings-change) didn't help?

Comment: or maybe [this](http://osdir.com/ml/Android-Developers/2010-01/msg03357.html). The idea I guess is that the system won't let you change the APN settings, but at least it will allow to open the APN settings screen. And that seems to me the natural way of doing it. Let the user shoot himself in the foot! ... don't risk doing it for him ;)

Comment: It is possible to write the APN settings programatically... I've done it with this application - I simply broke it and cannot seem to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: SVN update & override or GIT overwrite ?

Comment: Rolling back won't help either - I have a copy of my old working code - the problem is when we implemented a more secure server to send the XML data to the app - when it was a simple HTTP request without the authentication we're doing now it was functional - I just need to figure out how to get it to get and write the apn settings in this new configuration

Answer (score 1):

You can no longer programatically change APN settings on Android 4.0 and up. So if you're debugging on Android 4.0 or higher, that is where your issue is.

Comment: Nope... Android version 2.3.6

Comment: ...any other suggestions?